# Argument of type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js

i did'nt find a way to solve my problem :
Ts give me an :

```
 Argument of type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

I tried the solution i found here : [Argument of type 'DocumentData | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentData'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858982/argument-of-type-documentdata-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-ty)

but it is not working.

here my function :

```
async viewPost (post: { id?: unknown }) {
 const allCommentaires = await commentsCollection.where('postId', '==', post.id).get()
 if (allCommentaires) {
  allCommentaires.forEach(data => {
    const commentaires = data.data()
    commentaires.id = data.id
    if (commentaires !== undefined) {
      this.postComments.push(commentaires)
    }
  })
}
this.fullPost = post
this.showPostModal = true}
```

i get the error on this line :

```
this.postComments.push(commentaires)
```

commentaires have an underlined with error i wrote above

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that the solution you linked didn't work for you, but you could try asserting the type using the `as` keyword.

Also, you should move the data id assignment into the if statement, otherwise you risk getting the error `Cannot set property 'id' of undefined` at runtime:

```js
if (commentaires) {
  commentaires.id = data.id;
  this.postComments.push(commentaires as DocumentData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution :
here the change :

```
 async viewPost ({ state, commit }, post: { id?: any }): Promise<void> {
  const postComments: firebase.firestore.DocumentData[] = []
  const allCommentaires = await commentsCollection.where('postId', '==', post.id).get()
  if (allCommentaires) {
    allCommentaires.forEach(data => {
      const commentaires = data.data()
      commentaires.id = data.id
      if (commentaires !== undefined) {
        postComments.push(commentaires)
      }
    })
  }
},
```